# Mechanism of formation of peak of mass spectrum of isobutane at m/z = 27

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, mass-spectrometry

Here is the mass spectrum of isobutane:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nist.gov](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Spec=C75285&Index=0&Type=Mass))</sub>

Clearly the peak at $\mathrm{m/z} = 27$ corresponds to the species $\ce{C2H3+}$, the "protonated acetylene".

I am interested in possible formations for its formation from the molecular ion $\ce{t-BuH+}$.

Comment: Electron ionization fragmentation spectra, unlike say CID spectra, can be reasonably predicted computationally for small molecules.  This capability is only a few years old and is a major testament to how computational chemistry has advanced in the last few years.  Here's a recent review. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.jpca.6b02907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the first mass spectrometrists to see this ion were Stevenson and Hipple in 1942.<sup>1</sup>  They were puzzled by it.

Fifteen years later, Rosenstock and Melton explained the source of this ion in an exhaustive study.<sup>2</sup>  First, the molecular ion $\ce{C4H10+}$ dissociates into fragments via five possible pathways, each with its own activation energy.  See Table VIII in their paper, which I reproduce below.

[image: Table VIII from Rosenstock and Melton, 1957]

None of these primary dissociation pathways gives rise to $\ce{C2H3+}$.  Instead, it arises from a variety of processes from a subset (the *metastable* subset) of these five primary transitions.  These processes are shown in Tables X and XI of their paper.

[image: Tables X and XI from Rosenstock and Melton, 1957]

All of the reactions that give rise to $\ce{C2H3+}$ are probably happening to some extent, but the lowest-energy route there for isobutane (right column) appears to be via $\ce{C2H5+ -> C2H3+ + H2}$ (only 1.9 eV).  However, $\ce{C2H5+}$ itself requires more energy to form than $\ce{C3H7+}$ ($m/z=43$), so the route $\ce{C3H7+ -> C2H3+ + CH4}$ may also occur as well.

The general conclusions of their paper are worth quoting:

> The basic concept of the quasi-equilibrium theory is
> that mass spectra are formed by a series of competing
> consecutive unimolecular decomposition of excited ions.
> The results discussed above lend strong support to this
> concept. It was found that of several possible reactions
> of a given ion, the metastable transition was associated
> with the reaction having the least activation energy.
> The general rate equation appropriate for these systems
> is the product of a frequency factor and a function of
> the excitation energy $E$ and activation energy $\epsilon$. When
> the value of $E$ is such that the rate constant is of the
> order of $10^6~\mathrm{sec^{-1}}$, the rate constant is extremely
> sensitive to the value of $\epsilon$. The result is that a second
> reaction having an $\epsilon$ higher by more than a few tenths of
> an eV will have a considerably smaller rate constant,
> even if the frequency factor is larger by a factor of a
> thousand. Thus, in general, the correlation can be
> carried out in terms of activation energies alone.

#### References

1. [D. P. Stevenson, J. A. Hipple, Jr., *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1942,** *64* (7),  1588–1594.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01259a029)
2. [H. M. Rosenstock, C. E. Melton, *J. Chem. Phys.* **1957,** *26* (2), 314-322.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1743290)